# Xcode: Storyboard change presentations

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard, uistackview

Evening, I'm playing with Xcode storyboard and stack views inside a cell.

I have several stack nested.

When I load the app the presentation looks fine, but when I press into a row of the TableView, something happens and and Image view change the size :)

I'm sure that there is some kind of problem with constraints and stacks, but I can't find it, could you help me?

here's the git: https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/TwentyFour

Here some pictures:

[image: fine view]

[image: wrong view]

Comment: any tips? Please I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add fixes, not all, but it's working and you can fix rest by yourself.

https://github.com/OMGHaveFun/TwentyFour

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: Removed redundant stack views add missing constraints.